# Reading a pipe delimited file

Tags: java, file

I have the following file named ght.txt in my c: and it contains the following data

```
Id|ytr|yts
1|W|T
2|W|T
3|W|T
```

Now the thing is that positions of this columns (Id|ytr|yts) is also not in order means they can be reshuffled also..for ex

```
Id|ytr|dgfj|fhfjk|fgrt|yts
```

or they can be as ..

```
Id|wer|ytr|weg|yts
```

Now please advise how can I read this file through buffered writer in java and also the logic to catch only these column(Id|ytr|yts) as I need to first catch these columns and then need to store the value of the columns in a map.

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

It's the first line which provides positioning information,

```
String[] headers = firstLine.split("|");
int idIx, ytrIx, ytsIx, count = 0;
for(String header : headers) {
if(header.equals("Id")) {
  idIx = count;
}elseif (header.equals("ytr")) {
  ytrIx = count;
} elseif (header.equals("yts")) {
  ytsIx = count;
}
count++;
}
```

Now since you have these indexes, for each line after splitting use these indexes to retrieve desired value.

NOTE: If using `Java7`, use `switch-case` over header, if num headers are more you can use `HashMap` too for header-index mapping.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Commons CSV](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/) and specify the pipe as delimiter to load up the data, it then allows you to access data [based on header name](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/CSVRecord.html#get%28java.lang.String%29) to save you from having to do the "switch" stuff yourself.